# Will the security software that I am using on XP suffice for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I'm planning the move to Windows 7 (32-bit) and was wondering if I need to research more on security software and other utilities.

Basically, I'm wondering if the software I used on XP is still relevant for Windows 7? Or should I be researching for Windows 7 specific tools?

Right now I use:

- Avira
- a-squared
- Malwarebytes
- SUPER AntiSpyware
- Sandboxie
- CCleaner
- Defraggler

Is this good enough for now? Or should I be looking into some other tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those are all fine, although you'll probably need **newer, windows 7 compatible versions** of some, due to the increased security features (Relative to XP, anyway, it's a step down from vista!)

You can get these off their respective websites, so `everything's shiny, cap'n, not to fret.`

Comment: What you said! :)

Comment: Thanks! This will make the upgrade process a little less stressful :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both the responses. I would suggest to get Microsoft Security Essentials on windows 7.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion - find out if each is compatible with Windows 7. The kernel is different, the security is different.

CCleaner and Defraggler definitely work, but the newer versions preferably.